# Facebook Login for Android to use default browser

Tags: android, facebook

I integrated a Facebook sign in with my Android app following the rules:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

The documentation states:

> If people don't have the Facebook Android app installed, Facebook Login uses Facebook Lite instead to display the login screen and get credentials.

But a new screen requires to enter email/password on each open.

Is there a way to open a default system browser? I'm assuming many people are signed in on browser thus it would ease a friction to sign in into my app.

I could build a website sign in but I think there's no easy way to report back to the app a user ID (generating some kind of tokens in app?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Login tries to log in on Android via Facebook app or FBLite app if that is installed and then send to the default browser. The logic there is that a person is more likely to be logged in to their Facebook app if they have that on their device. You can specify if somebody is sent to Chrome Custom Tabs like this versus the default browser: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#chrome_custom_tabs

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in Your AndroidManifest It will open default chrome browser once you saved credentials in browser no need to enter username and password each time.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Here fb_login_protocol_scheme is

```
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbYOUR_FB_ID</string>
```